# Getting current frame from android vlc media player

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I'm using [VLC-Android](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android) in order to play H264 RTSP live stream in my android application, the following code successfully renders the stream video onto the surface view:

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(VLCInstance.get());
SurfaceView mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.player);

final IVLCVout vlcVout = Constants.mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
vlcVout.detachViews();
vlcVout.setVideoView(mSurfaceView);
vlcVout.setWindowSize(mSurfaceDims.getWidth(), mSurfaceDims.getHeight());
vlcVout.attachViews();
mSurfaceView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

Media media = new Media(VLCInstance.get(), Uri.parse(path));
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
mMediaPlayer.play();
```

**VLCInstance.java:**

```
package bi.anpr.vlc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCUtil;

public class VLCInstance {
    public final static String TAG = "VLC/Util/VLCInstance";

    private static LibVLC sLibVLC = null;

    /** A set of utility functions for the VLC application */
    public synchronized static LibVLC get() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (sLibVLC == null) {
            final Context context = VLCApplication.getAppContext();
            if(!VLCUtil.hasCompatibleCPU(context)) {
                Log.e(TAG, VLCUtil.getErrorMsg());
                throw new IllegalStateException("LibVLC initialisation failed: " + VLCUtil.getErrorMsg());
            }

            try{
                sLibVLC = new LibVLC(context);
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return sLibVLC;
    }

    public static synchronized void restart(Context context) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (sLibVLC != null) {
            sLibVLC.release();
            sLibVLC = new LibVLC(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer` renders the video on the SurfaceView after calling play() without any event that helps you to grab the current frame on the view, where i need to get the current frame each interval of time to perform some image processing on it.

**So is it possible using `vlc-android-sdk` to grab current frame, into a buffered image or an `OpenCV Mat`, while playing live streams or local video resources?**

Note that it is possible with java (desktop vlcj) through the **DirectMediaPlayer** class.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check this https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @AnjaniMittal yes I do without any aid neither from the VLC nor from the community, I will post the answer tomorrow hopefully, i'm just still making some tests

Comment: sure thnx, but I found an alternative today, using PixelCopy to fetch the screenshot of surface view and it's not blank, it's working totally fine, tried it. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @AnjaniMittal, please check my answer i think it would be much faster than using any third party tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd found a very simple an very fast solution to do this. Just use a **TextureView** instead of a **SurfaceView**, and then retrieve the image anytime while playing using the `getBitmap()` function as shown below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener,
        org.videolan.libvlc.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        org.videolan.libvlc.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        org.videolan.libvlc.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        org.videolan.libvlc.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener {

    private AppCompatActivity me = this;    
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;    
    private TextureView mTextureViewmTextureView;
    private String mUrl = "/storage/emulated/0/videos/test.mp4";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(VLCInstance.get());
        mTextureViewmTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    }

    private void attachViewSurface() {
            final IVLCVout vlcVout = mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
            mMediaPlayer.setScale(0);
            vlcVout.detachViews();
            vlcVout.setVideoView(mTextureView);
            vlcVout.setWindowSize(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            vlcVout.attachViews();
            mTextureView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }


    private void play(String path) {
       try {
            Media media;
            if (new File(path).exists()) {
                media = new Media(VLCInstance.get(), path);
            } else {
                media = new Media(VLCInstance.get(), Uri.parse(path));
            }

            mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
            mMediaPlayer.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
   }

   @Override
   public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
       attachViewSurface();

       if (mMediaPlayer.hasMedia())
           mMediaPlayer.play();
       else
           play(mUrl);
   }

   public Bitmap getImage() {
       return mTextureView.getBitmap();
   }

}
```

**VLCInstance.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCUtil;

public class VLCInstance {
    public final static String TAG = "VLC/Util/VLCInstance";

    private static LibVLC sLibVLC = null;

    /** A set of utility functions for the VLC application */
    public synchronized static LibVLC get() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (sLibVLC == null) {
            final Context context = VLCApplication.getAppContext();
            if(!VLCUtil.hasCompatibleCPU(context)) {
                Log.e(TAG, VLCUtil.getErrorMsg());
                throw new IllegalStateException("LibVLC initialisation failed: " + VLCUtil.getErrorMsg());
            }

            try{
                sLibVLC = new LibVLC(context);
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return sLibVLC;
    }

    public static synchronized void restart(Context context) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (sLibVLC != null) {
            sLibVLC.release();
            sLibVLC = new LibVLC(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's Work can you have any idea for recording RTSP live stream? and I also get a 1-sec dealy in my stream so if have any idea to solve this then please give me